# Can you make a jButton in a jFrame generate its code into another class?

Tags: java, button

Can you make a button in a jframe generate its Events>Action>actionPerformed code into another class besides the jframe class. If you cant, can you manually make the code in the different class to make the button do something.

Comment: Generate its code...?

Comment: Do you want to execute some action in another application? Or in another class inside the same application?

Comment: Yeah, when you right click the button on jframe

Comment: in another class inside the same application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Basically, you use `myJbutton.setActionListener(new MyButtonActionListener())`.

And you have a `class MyButtonActionListener implements ActionListener`. The method actionPerformed will be called automatically.

**EDIT**: Added code below

```
public class MyButtonActionListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(EventListener e){
        // Do stuff
    }
}
```

And you setup your button:

```
JButton myButton = new JButton("mybutton");
myButton.setActionListener(new MyButtonActionListener());
```

Comment: @Daniel, `not what im looking for` - then you need to clearly explain what it is that you are looking for.